# Bash cannot find any files at all

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am quite new to using Bash, so apologies if this is a rather rudimentary question;

I am trying to open a text file in Bash, but Bash does not seem to be able to find any of my files or directories at all. Whenever I try to use the `cat` command or `cd` command (for example, cd Desktop/), no matter what file or directory I specify, Bash tells me "No such file or directory". `pwd` says that I am in /mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32 . ls shows me a very long list of files, but none of them are that for which I am looking. I am trying to open a .txt file on my Desktop, but neither the Desktop nor the txt file are showing up in that list. I'm running Bash via the Linux subsystem on Windows 10.

Comment: What directory are you in? (check with `pwd`) What files *are* visible? (check with `ls`) BTW welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: The best would be to copy/paste a session transcript from a terminal window.

Comment: And perhaps [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1107619/316104) helps.

Comment: Have you tried cd-ing to your home folder (userprofile)? I think it'll be at `/mnt/c/Users/$USER`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He are tips to start with WSL:

Your windows files will be found at /mnt/c/

```
cd /mnt/c
```

from here use `ls` to see the folders and find the files you want to use, I personally tend to put the files I use with windows subsystem for linux on the C: directory for easier use, like `c:\FilesForWSL` you can just create the folder on windows or `cd /mnt/c` and `mkdir FilesForWsl` then `cd FilesForWsl`.

After this setup anytime you want to put a file to be used by windows or from windows into linux just go to `cd /mnt/c/FilesForWsl` substitute *FilesForWsl* with your preferred folder name. Hope this clarify a little how WSL works.